# Sailsjs combine date and time

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Im using sailsjs and Im trying to get all products have the startdate and starttime between two datetime. I dont know how to do it with sails model. How can I resolve this? Anything to combine two column like sql?

MyService.js:

```
    Obj.find({
        startDate: { '>=': sDate, '<=': eDate },
        startTime: { '>=': sTime, '<=': eTime }
    })
    .exec(function (err, model) {
        if(model && model.length == 0) {
            cb(err, model);     
            return;
        }
        cb(err, model);
    });
```

MySql Command:

```
SELECT * FROM Obj WHERE (TIMESTAMP(start_date, start_time) BETWEEN  '2017-03-20 05:02' AND '2017-03-21 05:02')
```

My table:

```
Name        Type
id          int
name        varchar
start_date  date
start_time  time
status      tinyint
```

Comment: Why do you have `startDate` and `startTime` in 2 different columns?

Comment: @Sangharsh It's hard to handle when I only want to use date or time

Comment: In my opinion, it is easier to extract `date` or `time` from a `datetime` field than other way round. In your query if you want 24 hour window, it is still easier to write but consider getting rows between `2017-03-01 02:10:00` and `2017-03-03 04:15:00` (for example). It will result in unnecessary complex query.

Comment: You can use [`.query()`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) to use MySQL raw queries from Sails.